# HTML inputs ignore flex-basis CSS property

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-input

Somewhy inputs do not perceive flex-basis correctly. Here is a simplest example illustrating how inputs do not obey and span outside of their parent block (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL40dgq1/)):

```
<div>
    <input>
    <input>
</div>

<style>     
    div { display: flex; width: 200px; border: 2px solid red; }
    input { flex-basis: 50%; }
</style>
```

Here is [another, more comprehensive, case](https://codepen.io/zomigi/pen/WxqgdY).

What the hell? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` elements has an *instrinsic* `width` - and width of flex items (along the flex axis) default to `auto`. Reset this using `min-width: 0` - see demo below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

input {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: That works. Thank you!